# unintended space above the table when with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a `table` into a "`span6`" `div` that is nested into a "`row-fluid`" `div`.

I want this table to span all the width possible (span6 in the example) and everything works fine, but a gap between the table and the first element above it is generated. It shouldn't be a margin, because I tried to set it to 0, so I really don't have a clue what's going on and I ask your help! Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynyex/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The h3 tag has a 10px margin pushing it down from the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ynyex/3/

```
.borderTest{
    border: 1px solid red;
        margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Silly me! I tried to simplify a piece of code I was working on, but your answer is absolutely correct and it helped me to spot the problem  as well. Thanks!
The problem was a `div` with class `btn-group` that was nested into the `h5` element: its `height` was too high and it was affecting the table below